# Return response of another function on a href click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I'm trying to return the result of a bootstrap modal on click of an a tag, in this case used as a delete button. On click of the delete button I want a modal to pop up confirming the deletion and if the user clicks no, return `false` and if they click yes, return `true`.

This is what I have so far:

```
$('.btn.delete').on('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation(); // There is a listener on the entire row the buttons are on, this prevents the event bubbling up and triggering that listener.
    return modal('Are you sure?', 'Once deleted a user cannot be recovered, are you sure you wish to delete this user?', 'No', 'Yes', function(result) {
        return ! result;
    })
});

var numModals = 0;
function modal(title, content, btn1, btn2, callback) {
    if( ! btn1) {
        btn1 = 'OK';
    }

    var thisModal = numModals++;

    $('body').append('<div id="modal-dialogue-'+thisModal+'" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-dialogue-'+thisModal+'" aria-hidden="true">\
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">\
        <div class="modal-content">\
          <div class="modal-header">\
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>\
            <h3 id="modal-title">'+title+'</h3>\
          </div>\
          <div class="modal-body">\
            <p>'+content+'</p>\
          </div>\
          <div class="modal-footer">\
            <button class="btn btn-inverse" data-dismiss="modal" id="modal-btn-'+thisModal+'-1">'+btn1+'</button>\
            '+(btn2 !== undefined && btn2.length > 0 ? '<button class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" id="modal-btn-'+thisModal+'-2">'+btn2+'</button>' : '')+'\
          </div>\
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->\
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->\
    </div><!-- /.modal -->');

    $('#modal-dialogue-'+thisModal).modal().on('hidden', function() {
        $(this).data('modal', null).remove();
    });

    if($.isFunction(callback)) {
        $('#modal-btn-'+thisModal+'-1').on('click', function() {
            callback(true);
            $('#modal-dialogue-'+thisModal).modal('hide').data('modal', null).remove();
        });
        $('#modal-btn-'+thisModal+'-2').on('click', function () {
            callback(false)
            $('#modal-dialogue-'+thisModal).modal('hide').data('modal', null).remove();
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is the "click" event doesn't wait for the response of the modal call, it just goes straight through to the delete page. How can I make the button wait for the response from the modal and then continue to the delete page or stop depending on the response of the modal?

Comment: If you're going to down vote please leave a reason why so I can improve my question. Arbitrary down voting helps no one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to prevent the default action of the `<a>` tag.

Calling `event.preventDefault()` should do it.

```
$('.btn.delete').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default action of the <a> tag - do not go directly into the link.
    event.stopPropagation(); // There is a listener on the entire row the buttons are on, this prevents the event bubbling up and triggering that listener.
    return modal('Are you sure?', 'Once deleted a user cannot be recovered, are you sure you wish to delete this user?', 'No', 'Yes', function(result) {
        return ! result;
    })
});
```

Then, to make the button work just save the link into a variable and set the `window.location` there on confirmation.

```
$('.btn.delete').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default action of the <a> tag - do not go directly into the link.
    event.stopPropagation(); // There is a listener on the entire row the buttons are on, this prevents the event bubbling up and triggering that listener.

    var link = $(this).attr("href");

    return modal('Are you sure?', 'Once deleted a user cannot be recovered, are you sure you wish to delete this user?', 'No', 'Yes', function(result) {
        if(result)
            window.location = link;
        return ! result;
    })
});
```

Comment: I've tried that, if I have that then the button does nothing whether modal returns true or false.

Comment: @Styphon - I updated the answer, you'll just need to save the link href to a variable and then set the `window.location` variable there on confirm - Check the edit! Thanks.

Comment: Great I could help @Styphon :)!